# Sqlalchemy Nested Query Returns Wrong data

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, nested

I have this SQL expression:

```
SELECT count(*), date_trunc('day', data)
from (
select max(hc.acesso) as data 
from historico_comunicacao hc
join cliente c on (c.id = hc.id_cliente)
group by c.id
having max(hc.acesso) between ('2012-11-30') and ('2012-12-07 23:59:59')
order by max(hc.acesso) desc
) as x


GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

**So, I did so in SqlAlchemy:**

```
nestedQuery = session.query(func.max(MapComunicacao.acesso).label('data'))\
.join(MapCliente)\
.group_by(MapCliente.id)\
.having(func.max(MapComunicacao.acesso).between(dataini, dataFinal))\
.order_by(desc(func.max(MapComunicacao.acesso)))

query = session.query(
    func.count(nestedQuery.subquery().columns.data),
        extract('day', nestedQuery.subquery().columns.data)
)\
.group_by('anon_3.data')


result = query.all()
```

No error occurs, but the data returned are wrong for me.

I have two tables: Cliente (Customer) and Historico_Acesso (Access_History). What I want to know is the total number of customers who have talked to my DataBase for the last time, grouped by date.

Like this:

Total        Date

19;        "2012-12-07 00:00:00+00"

16;        "2012-12-06 00:00:00+00"

20;        "2012-12-05 00:00:00+00"

06;        "2012-12-04 00:00:00+00"

06;        "2012-12-03 00:00:00+00"

01;        "2012-12-02 00:00:00+00"

04;        "2012-12-01 00:00:00+00"

09;        "2012-11-30 00:00:00+00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess: try to extract `nestedQuery.subquery()` into a variable, so that it's called only once.

If that doesn't work, SQLAlchemy will gladly print the generated SQL for you with `print query`. You can then compare with your handcrafted SQL query.